# getting "slice bounds out of range" error on iterating over a slice and modifying it via "append()"

Tags: go, slice

I have written a function to replace sequence of repeated words by just one word in a slice of strings([]string). I use "range" to loop over the slice and use "append()" to modify the slice. Below is the code:

```
func RemoveContinuosStrings(input []string) []string {  
        top:=0

        for i,_ := range input {
                if input[i] != input[top] {
                        if top != i-1 {
                                input = append(input[:top+1], input[i:]...)
                        }   
                        top = i 
                }   
        }   
        return input[:top+1]
}

func main() {

        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Println("enter text")
        input := make([]string, 0, 0)

        for scanner.Scan() {
                input = append(input, scanner.Text())
        }   

        fmt.Println("INPUT", input)
        input = RemoveContinuosStrings(input)
        fmt.Println("OUTPUT", input)
}
```

on executing the above code I see following error:

```
===================================================  
    vignesh@vignesh-ThinkPad-E470 ~/go-book/chapter4 $ ./4_6_eliminate_duplicate_string  
    enter text
    qwe
    asd
    asd
    zxc
    asd
    asd
    INPUT [qwe asd asd zxc asd asd]
    panic: runtime error: index out of range

    goroutine 1 [running]:
    main.RemoveContinuosStrings(0xc420088000, 0x6, 0x8, 0x20, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/vignesh/go-book/chapter4/4_6_eliminate_duplicate_string.go:11 +0x2a0
    main.main()
        /home/vignesh/go-book/chapter4/4_6_eliminate_duplicate_string.go:33 +0x33a
    vignesh@vignesh-ThinkPad-E470 ~/go-book/chapter4 $ 
=======================================================
```

So, is t wrong or not allowed to append to the slice being iterated via "range". I saw several examples online where they did append to the slice but were iterating without using "range" (eg: for i=0; i< lenOfSlice; i++). Please help/correct me if I am wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are changing array size inside a loop, remember to use simple for instead of for range

```
func RemoveContinuosStrings(input []string) []string {
    top:=0

    for i:=0;i<len(input);i++ {
        if input[i] != input[top] {
            if top != i-1 {
                input = append(input[:top+1], input[i:]...)
                i=top+1
                top=top+1
            }else{
                top = i
            }
        }
    }
    return input[:top+1]
}
```

Comment: so, is it wrong to change array size inside loop while using "range"??

Comment: Go uses a copy of the value instead of the value itself within a range clause. So when we take the pointer of value, we’re actually taking the pointer of a copy of the value. This copy gets reused throughout the range clause. However, when you change array size, the original data is changed but noting would happen for the copy which is being used by range clause

Comment: thanks for helping me with your comment and code snippet. Before posting the question here, I had looked a lot online to know any such conditions for "range" but couldn't find any help. So, Could you pls let me know from where or how did you got to know the answer??

Comment: this may help you : https://medium.com/@betable/3-go-gotchas-590b8c014e0a